# iWeb 3.0.4 Save to Folder Problem

Tags: iweb

I want to publish my website on a private server, but I can't seem to find an option to "save to folder" on my current version of iWeb.  What do I need to do to save my files to a folder so that I can upload them to a server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the "publishing" method on the top level of the web site you are editing:

[image]

Comment: I want to add that once you do this, you then need to go to FILE -> Publish Entire Site