# Publishing to folder on iWeb produces strange A^ symbol

Tags: iweb

I published a website to a folder using iWeb following the proceedures indicated on [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/104649/iweb-3-0-4-save-to-folder-problem) posting.

After publishing, I clicked on VISIT SITE NOW and everything looked fine.

I then proceeded to upload it onto my server and I now see a strange phenomenon occurring.

On almost every carriage return, the new line begins with a strange "A^" symbol.

You can see the results of this on [this website](http://www.math.utep.edu/siam/SIAM/Seminar.html).

Is there something that I'm doing wrong?  What can I do to prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

This probably indicates your web server is configured to force all browsers to use Latin-1 encoding.  iWeb pages are always in UTF-8 encoding.  Ask the people who run the server to fix it.  This can usually be done by adding a special .htaccess file to your web space.